# Visual Studio 2010 working directory

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm developing a C# asp.net web application. I'm basically done with it, but I have this little problem. I want to save xml files to the "Users" folder within my project, but if I don't psychically hard code the path "C:......\Users" in my project it wants to save the file in this "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0\Users" folder, this is an annoying problem because I can't use the hard coded directory on our web hosts server. Also, I have a checkbox list that populates from the the "DownloadLibrary" folder in my project, and its suppose to download the files from that fold but its also looking to the "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0\" folder for download even though its populating from the correct folder. I'm very confused by this, its the first time something like this has ever happened to me. Can anyone please help me with this, its the only thing standing in my way to complete this project.

Comment: I think you might want physically rather than psychically, which would be a particularly hard thing to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use the working directory at all; you want to use a directory relative to where the web application is located (which can be retrieved from [`HttpRequest.ApplicationPath`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.applicationpath.aspx).

```
HttpRequest request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
// get the physical path to the web application
string pathToApp = request.MapPath(request.ApplicationPath);
string usersPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(pathToApp, "Users");
```

**Update**
As [VincayC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/417057/vinayc) points out; asp.net development is not my strongest skill ;) The above code is essentially equivalent of this (much simpler) code:

```
string usersPath = HttpRequest.Current.Request.MapPath("~/Users");
```

If this code appears in the code-behind of a page, you can probably cut `HttpContext.Current` as well, since the page has a `Request` property.

Comment: +1, but perhaps simpler way would be request.MapPath("~/Users")!

Comment: Thanks man this was a great help, sure fixed the problem I have

Answer (score 0):

That did fix the one problem I'm having, but the downloads are still not downloading from the right place, the program still wants to get the files from "C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\microsoft shared\DevServer\10.0\" directory here is the code I'm using

--Code to populate the checkbox--

```
HttpRequest request = HttpContext.Current.Request;
// get the physical path to the web application
string appPath = request.MapPath(request.ApplicationPath);
string directory = System.IO.Path.Combine(appPath, "DownloadLibrary/");

// Get the list of files into the CheckBoxList
var dirInfo = new DirectoryInfo(directory);

cblFiles.DataSource = dirInfo.GetFiles();
cblFiles.DataBind();
```

--Download Button Code--

```
// Tell the browser we're sending a ZIP file!
            var downloadFileName = string.Format("Items-{0}.zip", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd-HH_mm_ss"));
            Response.ContentType = "application/zip";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "filename=" + downloadFileName);
```

// Zip the contents of the selected files
        using (var zip = new ZipFile())
        {
            // Add the password protection, if specified
            /*if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtZIPPassword.Text))
            {
                zip.Password = txtZIPPassword.Text;

                // 'This encryption is weak! Please see http://cheeso.members.winisp.net/DotNetZipHelp/html/24077057-63cb-ac7e-6be5-697fe9ce37d6.htm for more details
                zip.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.WinZipAes128;
            }*/

            // Construct the contents of the README.txt file that will be included in this ZIP
            var readMeMessage = string.Format("Your ZIP file {0} contains the following files:{1}{1}", downloadFileName, Environment.NewLine);

            // Add the checked files to the ZIP
            foreach (ListItem li in cblFiles.Items)
                if (li.Selected)
                {
                    // Record the file that was included in readMeMessage
                    readMeMessage += string.Concat("\t* ", li.Text, Environment.NewLine);

                    // Now add the file to the ZIP (use a value of "" as the second parameter to put the files in the "root" folder)
                    zip.AddFile(li.Value, "Your Files");
                }


            // Add the README.txt file to the ZIP
            //zip.AddEntry("README.txt", readMeMessage, Encoding.ASCII);


            // Send the contents of the ZIP back to the output stream
            zip.Save(Response.OutputStream);</pre></code>

I'm not sure how to get the downloads to point to my application directory,I tried everything I can think off.